# Two same programs using Boost::tokenizer, but two different outputs

Tags: c++, boost

The following C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

    string s ("(0,30,0)");

    tokenizer tokens(s.substr(1,s.size()-2), boost::char_separator<char>(","));
    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin(); tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
        cout<<*tok_iter<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

has a problem since it outputs `0 0 0` instead of `0 30 0`...

But if I slightly change it like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

    string s ("(0,30,0)");

    //Modified lines:
    string t (s.substr(1,s.size()-2));
    tokenizer tokens(t, boost::char_separator<char>(","));

    for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin(); tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
        cout<<*tok_iter<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It works correctly! How is this possible ? At first sight, I would think that the two versions are the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, `s.substr(1,s.size()-2)` returns a **temporary object** and its lifetime expires at the end of the expression. However, `boost::tokenizer` has a constructor that takes a const reference, which means that the lifetime of the object will now be extended for as long as that reference exists. The problem is that `boost::tokenizer` only stores iterators to the passed in reference, so the reference to the object expires and the iterators are now invalid.

Comment: I wonder why the boost::tokenizer class doesn't have (and initialize) a `const string &` data member, just for the purpose of extending the lifetime of temporaries passed, exactly as in this situation?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: That would create a dangling reference. Once the `const string&` of the constructor expires the data member would be referring to expired memory. The only way to ensure the string is valid is to copy the string into a data member which can affect performance.